# Convert code to exe or GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface

I am a beginner to programming, and I have started to learn Python. I am trying to create a search and replace application, which allows us to select a number of files and then replaces the words or phrases that we want.

I have already written that script, but I want to make something which works in Windows XP.
Actually I want it to be a GUI application that works in Windows. So what am I supposed to do? Here's the code that I have written:

```
#replace.py
import string
def main():
    filez = raw_input("which files do you want processed?")
    f=open(filez,"r")
    data=f.read()
    w1=raw_input("what do you want to replace?")
    w2= raw_input("what do you want to replace with?")
    print data
    data=data.replace(w1,w2)
    print data
    f=open(filez,"w")
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Python has quite a few gui options, these in my mind are the most prolific.

- [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)
- [pygtk](http://www.pygtk.org/)
- [pyqt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro)

since you said your a beginner I'd recommend using Tkinter as it comes built into python. [Here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/) is a tutorial to get you started.

Comment: I also need to know one more thing. do I need to be good at object oriented programming before I start using tkinter?

Comment: @faraz, as long as you understand basic object oriented concepts (inheritance), you should be able to make a pretty simple interface. Also since you are using python, which is a very object oriented language, the more you know about object oriented better off you will be. What I'm getting at is if you decide to use python do yourself a favor and get good at object oriented programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can create windows executable using, for example, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). If you really need GUI I recommend [wxpython project](http://www.wxpython.org/).

Also, I recommend use some specialized utility for this task, for example, [fart-it](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/). This is a command-line utility so you can simply write GUI wrapper on python and run it. This utility already tested and more complicated than your script, so it can run faster and more safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

I was involved in a GUI project recently and begun using [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) and would definitely recommend it for beginners. 
You can develop the GUI using [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/), it will help a lot in learning wxPython itself. (Take extra time to make sure you understand the concept of Sizers because they're a fundamental and powerful concept to GUI develpement)
You can then use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)to convert your python script into an executable that can be run on Windows.
With regards to your script, lines involving `raw_input(something)` should be replaced with textboxes or prompts. To display texts you can use textboxes as well.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a Python GUI application which can be run in windows xp without python installed in the machine, right? 
If yes, then to create GUI application use pyQT toolkit which is kind of easy and to make .exe file of your script use pyinstaller. 
Both are easy to use and easy to learn.